# Cascading location menu logic

Tags: json, angularjs, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to make a cascading menu, where user can select location.

1. I am loading countries from one JSON
2. Once country is selected I will show State select, but only if is this country has states division, if not then step 3
3. Show city selection

Here is what I think about JSON organisation:

countries.json - for countries

US_states.json - for states, where first 2 letters are country code

US_CA_cities.json - for cities

EE_cities.json - for cities of the countries where is no state division.

Question #1: how better organise loading of JSON files, so I can load them when needed. For example, when user selects US, then I will load JSON with list of states. Once user selected state, I will load list of assosiated cities.

Question#2: when there is no state in the country, I need to go directly to 
city selection, how I can skip the state selection step. Maybe check based on JSON file names?

Here is a working Plunkr with what I did so far:
[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zUUVXIITxGLKBatVLGjV?p=preview)

```
app.controller('LocationCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.country = {};
$scope.countries = [ 
    {name: 'Estonia', code: 'EE', hasStates: false},
    {name: 'United States', code: 'US', hasStates: true}

}]);
```

Comment: 1) Current json organisation seems ok to me. 2) Add extra field to country to indicate where it has state division or not: {name: 'Estonia', code: 'EE', hasStates: false }

Comment: I am more of a web designer, working on a prototype, so I am having hard time writing something new myself. I better learn by reading working code. :) I have updated Plunkr, so now each country has "hasState" property. But how to load cities and states based on country selection and skip states if "hasState:false", still above my current knowledge. Can someone advice and update my Plunkr code, I cleaned it to the bare minimum